# Angular - Router unit testing with testing module and RouterMock

Tags: angular, unit-testing, routes, jasmine, angular2-routing

I've read several questions about how to unit test routing. But nothing fits my case really. I have a navbar-comp. with several `[routerLink]=[...]`
And when I simulate a click event. I want for instance to call `expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(*path*);`

But I am already failing on the test setup: It throws me everytime a: `cannot find root of undefined`.

### Test suite

```
describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;

  const router: Router = jasmine.createSpyObj('Router', ['navigate']);

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: Router, useValue: router}
      ],
      declarations: [
        NavbarComponent,
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should navigate on click - home', () => {
    (<jasmine.Spy>router.navigate).and.stub();
    const debugElm = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#navLogo');
    debugElm.click();

    expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/stories']);
  });
```

When I delete the `RoutingTestingModule` import then it throws me: `Cannot bind to routerLink` - which I actually need to test. Really frustrating... Does anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RouterTestingModule already provides a mock Router instance so there is no need to provide one explicitly in the test. Try something like that:

```
describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
  let component: NavbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
  let navigateSpy: Spy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        NavbarComponent,
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    navigateSpy = spyOn(TestBed.get(Router), 'navigate'); // <= init spy 
  });

  it('should navigate on click - home', () => {
    const debugElm = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#navLogo');
    debugElm.click();

    expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/stories']); // <= check spy
  });
```

Comment: I think you meant `let navigateSpy: jasmine.Spy`.